# Issues testing hapijs plugin

Tags: hapi.js, hapi.js-lab

Here's my test

```
'use strict';

var assert = require('assert');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
var Lab = require('lab');

var lab = exports.lab = Lab.script();

lab.experiment("src.mysql", function () {

    var server = {
        settings: {
            app: {
                mysql: {
                    connectionLimit: 10,
                    host: "none",
                    user: "me",
                    password: "nope",
                    database: "db"

                }
            }
        },
        expose: sinon.stub()
    };
    var mysql = sinon.stub();
    var next = sinon.stub();
    var plugin = proxyquire('../../src/mysql', {
        mysql: mysql
    });

    lab.test("successful loads", function(done) {
        plugin.register(server, {}, next, function(err) {
            assert(err === 'hello');
        });

        done();
    });
});
```

I'm not getting an error, but the test is passing, which is a false positive. Not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of hapi 8.x.x uses a new method for loading plugins, you should call server.register with arguments described here http://hapijs.com/api#serverregisterplugins-options-callback.

Comment: I updated my question with the latest test. Still not getting the results I expect

Comment: You are not using api correctly, the server object you are registering is not a hapi plugin object